# Javascript Preview and WMD are inconsistent on headings (or WMD has developed telepathy)

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown-preview

The preview shows non-bold text for H2 level headings like `## Overview` as shown here:

[image]

I don't think this stands out well.  I thought about changing it, but I decided it wasn't worth the effort.  However, I let it slide, and lo and behold it rendered in bold, just like I wanted it to!

[image]

If the rendering engine has been improved from WYSIWYG to semantic syntax to telepathic inference, then let me congratulate the devs on this accomplishment.

Otherwise, it's a bug in the otherwise perfect Javascript rendering tool.

Comment: This looks to be a css issue between the preview and the actual answer styles.  Talking to the designer king now.

Answer (score 1):

I have put in a fix, it will be live after the next production build.